# RIP routing: Always same network address

Tags: routes, ip, cisco, telecommunication

I can't seem to find out why, but when adding a network ip address while configuring the rip routing mechanism on a router, the addresses always seems to fallback on the same address.

In fact, in my case, all the address of my 192.168.1.0 /24 were divided in 14 sub-network (including pc networks and connection networks) and were set in a static way.

The router 1 is connected to a pc networks (192.168.1.0 /27) and the following connection network (serial link between two routers - 192.168.1.220 /30). When I try to add the previous networks, it always fallsback to 192.168.1.0. I can't seem to understand why.

I did the following commands on the router 1 :

```
> router rip
> network 192.168.1.0
> network 192.168.1.220
```

And then, when I go on the config page in Packet Tracer, it only shows the network 192.168.1.0. It does the same with all my routers.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to run RIPv2 with the `no auto-summary` option. The original RIP was a classful routing protocol, and the class for any address beginning with the bits `110` is Class C with a `/24` mask length.

Also, the network commands don't actually give a routing protocol the actual networks to advertise, they give the routing protocol the network interfaces which to use (e.g. any interface with an address in the `192.168.1.0/24` range).